# PowerPivot Managment dashboard 2016 not extracting Usage.Requests during Usage data Collection

Tags: powerpivot, bi, office-online-server

After upgrading to SharePoint 2016 
we noticed that the Usage.Requests table in the PowerPivot Service Application database is not being populated.

all the other tables are storing information, but that one remains empty

Also the usage.Documents is not populating the document metadata like owner, filename, last modified, created, etc.

This wasn't mentioned on things deprecated by powerpivot, could something cause a problem to extract that data into powerpivot service application database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**S**tarting with SQL Server 2012 Power Pivot for SharePoint, the SharePoint usage database is not used for Power Pivot usage collection.

In upgrade or migration scenarios where you may have older usage data still in the SharePoint usage databases , you can use

> **Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Processing timer job**

Which can be manually run to move any remaining Power Pivot related data in the SharePoint usage database to the Power Pivot service application databases.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/power-pivot-sharepoint/power-pivot-usage-data-collection?view=sql-analysis-services-2017

Comment: Thank you #A.Saéed, but I ran the timer job and still no result of the requests